# How to create code snippet syntax highlighted box HTML, CSS, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I in my application I need to show code snippets of user entered code

How can I create code snippets styled with syntax highlights using HTML, CSS, JS or may Jquery like these examples -

Example 1 of Carbon Website

[image]

Example 2 of W3 School

[image]

Example 3 of Stack Overflow

```
// As you can see this code snippet image or customized code box
//this is the example of stackoverflow website

const simpleConst = "How can I create this type of code snippets by using Html CSS Js";

console.log(simpleConst);
```

any help will be always appreciated :)

Comment: Search for [js syntax highlighter](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+syntax+highlighter), there are a lot of them.

Comment: @vee thank you for this information. I think it will help

Answer (score 2):

I understand your questions like You wanna make code blocks in HTML Screen.

maybe You should see this article.
https://css-tricks.com/web-component-for-a-code-block/

and make user input or textarea for typing code ...

```
    <div>
      <input id="textElm" />
      <br />
      <code id="codeElm">hi</code>
    </div>
```

```js
const input = document.getElementById("textElm");
const code = document.getElementById("codeElm");

input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log(code)
  code.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

or use https://highlightjs.org/

Comment: I thinks so too.
If you want to highlighting code for share blog post.
just wrap the code in <code></code>

Comment: or Use github gist